# What is the "warp allocation granularity", and what purpose does it serve in CUDA register allocation?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

In CUDA, register pages are allocated on a per-thread-group basis. These group units are either blocks, on sm_1x devices, or warps, on sm_2x and sm_3x devices. Registers are allocated in register pages, and thus are always allocated im multiples of the register page size - the CUDA occupancy calculator calls it the "register allocation granularity".

I understand this much. What I do not understand is why register pages are only allocatable to thread group units if the number of warps in these groups is a multiple of the "warp allocation granularity". The programming guide, and the wider internet, mention little about this technicality.

What is the purpose of enforcing this other level of register allocation granularity besides the register page size granularity? Might it have anything to do with the number of warp schedulers present of the device? It isn't clear to me why, if this is indeed the case.

Best regards,
James.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Warp Allocation Granularity is a constraint in the hardware resource allocation.

On SM1.x-2.x resources are allocated 2 warps at a time.

On SM3.x-5.x resources are allocated 4 warps at a time.

If the kernel configuration is N then the hardware allocates resources for N rounded up to a multiple of WarpAllocationGranularity.

This limitation reduces the control logic and allocation table sizes thus reducing area and power.